# How to create the editor grid panel with textfield column in extjs 3

Tags: jsp, extjs

I have created one editor grid panel using extjs in that grid panel by default columns should load with the textfield

```
var Grid= new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store:checkpoint,
    renderTo:'testgrid',
    autoHeight:true, 
    border:false,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    columns: [ {header:'Check Points',
                 menuDisabled: true,
             dataIndex: 'checkpoints',
             valueField:'Id',
             width:300,
            },
             {
                 menuDisabled: true,
                 header:'Report',
                 dataIndex: 'developerreport',
                 renderer:  function (v,p) {
                     p.attr += ' ext:qtip=" click to edit"';
                     return v; 
                   } ,

                 editor:  new Ext.form.ComboBox({

                    hideTrigger: true, 
                    name: 'comment',
                    id:'comment',
                    mode: 'local',
                    store: names,
                    displayField: 'role',
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    emptyText:'Select Role',
                    allowBlank:     false,
                    editable:       false,
                    forceSelection: true}),},
                   {header:'Comment',
                     menuDisabled: true,
                     dataIndex: 'developercomment',
                     renderer:  function (v,p) {
                        p.attr += ' ext:qtip=" click to add"';
                         return v;
                      } ,

                     editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
                        }),}],
              viewConfig: {
                    deferEmptyText: false,
                    forceFit: true,
                    emptyText: '<p style="font-size: 13px;color:red;">Please fill the above details</p>',
                    },

                });
```

I want comment field should load with textbox, is there any ways to do

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to have a textfield right away, without entering edit mode?

Comment: yes i need like textbox before entering into edit mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do it with `EditorGridPanel` straight away, because AFAIK it supports one editor at the time. Probably the easiest solution is to create renderer which renders content as HTML `input` and then attach event's to that input. You can also create component for each HTML input using `applyTo` config property.

Working sample that uses `applyTo`: http://jsfiddle.net/N2wYX/6/